# Mysql error with wildcard and array replacement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following db query that is looking up rows in a MySql table that end in a certain pattern.

```
$res = db_query('SELECT identifier FROM {rules_scheduler} WHERE identifier LIKE %:schid', array(':schid' => '_' . $sch_id));
foreach ($res as $rec) {
    scheduler_delete_schedule($component, $rec->identifier);
}
```

But this results in the following error...

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%'_591'' at line 1: SELECT identifier FROM {rules_scheduler}
>   WHERE identifier LIKE %:schid; Array ( [:schid] => _591 ) in
>   _callback_delete_scheduled_notifications()

So it looks like my :schid token is correctly being replaced with _591 , but there seems to be a single inverted comma between the % and the under score. I cant for the life of me figure out why!

Comment: I think, query should be LIKE \'%;child\'.

Comment: What does the semi colon mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean :

Comment: The wildcard goes in the binding. Also an `_` is a single character is that what you intend, I'd think the `%` would cause issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `{rules_scheduler}` is supposed to be, so I'll provide you with a query string that works with the wildcard:

```
$query = "SELECT identifier FROM rules_scheduler WHERE identifier LIKE CONCAT('%', :schid)";

$res = db_query($query, [':schid' => '_' . $sch_id]);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, that worked a treat. In regards to the table, in db_query in drupal you define a table like {table_name}